# Tweet params with twitter API

Tags: html, api, twitter, mean

I want to have this template to tweet a String+Params like this:

```
    <td><a  class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"
 href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=I%20found%20an%20object"+{{itemFound.type}} 
data-size="large"></a></td>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Apparently it was like this:

```
  <td><a  class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"
 href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=I%20found%20an%20object+{{itemFound.type}}" 
data-size="large"></a></td>
```